# Add restriction on discriminator (class type) to select subset of classes in fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover, discriminator

I'm using fluent nhibernate with Discriminator for subclasses. (very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119432/how-to-query-nhibernate-for-specific-type))

For example, assume I have classes Cat, Dog, and Racoon that extend abstract class Animal.

I want to be able to select both Cat, And Dog but leave out Racoon. So

```
return _db.CreateCriteria<Cat>.List<Cat>();
```

will not work for me as getting list of cats and dogs and merging them seems like a wrong way of doing it.

I've tried doing

```
this.AndRestrictionOn(Restrictions.In(...))
```

and it's variants but it always results in errors.

Is there a way I can specify what subclasses I want in the Query Object, please?

---

Digging through some more, I found out you can do that [in HQL](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-where)

```
 from Eg.Cat cat where cat.class = Eg.DomesticCat
```

But I am still unable to convert that into ICriteria / Query object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work

```
this.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("class", typeof(Cat)))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("class", typeof(Dog))));
```

See http://www.nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-where

Answer (score 0):

```
Animal animal = null;

QueryOver<Animal>(() => animal)
 .Where(() => animal.GetType().IsIn(new[] { Animals.Cat.ToString(), Animals.Dog.ToString() }))
```

Where Animals is your Discriminator-Enum